# how to store registered users info in azure?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database

I am developing a chat application for windows phone using c# and I would like to first maintain the registered users when they register in my application. I am planning to get them registered with their live account authentication.

Any suggestions on how to store(database table format) the registered users information and maintain that information in windows azure mobile?

And how do I uniquely identify each user (apart from live id ) so that I can push the notifications ? One solution I think is by using subscription uri from MPNS .

Comment: If I were you, I would be careful about how you store them. Don't associate a single login with a single user - you will hate yourself later for doing so. Instead, allow a single user to specify many different logins (Yahoo, Live, Google, etc) so that way they can use **any** of them to log into the same single account in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [MobileService.LoginAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj553650.aspx) you'll get the user id per whatever auth provider you used, and then that (potentially opaque) value is automatically pushed into your Mobile Services scripts via user parameter (presuming you set the script to require authenticated users).   The [Get started with authentication in Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet/) tutorial covers most of this, and you'd simply store the user id with whatever 'friendly' profile name, info you're also collecting.

The Live Id (Microsoft account) would already uniquely identify each user, though it's certainly possible that a given user has multiple devices have multiple devices he or she is using to access your app.  Typically your app would register/renew its notification channel URI on startup (because the URI can expire) and associate it with the user id (Live, Twitter, etc.), store it in a table in WAMS, and then when you want to notify user X, you send a push notification to each URI associated with that user in the database table - that's a fairly simple select off the table storing the URIs and user info.